# XML Parsing for removing of embeded HTML tags like b, i with Array

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

XML which I get from webservice has an element node like:

```
<data>This is <b>Bold</b> data with <i>Italics</i> data in it </data>
```

When I parse the XML to array what I get is:

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [b] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bold
            )

        [i] => Array
            (
                [0] => Italics
            )

        [0] => This is  data with  data in it
    )
```

Here i want to skip tags like b, i, etc. Please suggest some method.

NOTE: Data is not in CDATA else the things would have been more than simple.

Comment: Also the code how you parse the XML is missing. Also you have to create a self-containing example with as little data and code as *necessary* to reproduce your issue. Please write this from scratch and add it to your question. Because so far, it is not possible to reproduce what you ask about.

Comment: Hi Hakre, Its not a duplicate as I can see, its a totally new question

Comment: *"totally new"* - absolutely not! Write your code now. Then tell us what does not work and why you think it should work. As I already elaborated it's less about if there is a duplicate or not, it's just that you do not ask a question here that fits well for this website. - BTW the exact duplicate is here: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456) - as your question is asking for reference (*"Please suggest some method"*).